# PHP Array: Check if exists

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

So I have this code which create a large array of countries.

```
            $newCountry = array(
                'reservation_id' => $countryId,
                'amount' => $countryAmount,
                'iso' => $countryIso,
                'start' => $event['start']
            );
            
            if(!$countryId == null){
                array_push($eventsCountries, $newCountry);
            }
```

I would like to sort like this = [CountryIso] => ([0] => ItemArray)
And if start date already exists in the CountryIso array, add the amount to the currently existing amount.

My code have created so far.

$t2 = [];foreach ($eventsCountries as $item) {

```
$t2 = [];foreach ($eventsCountries as $item) {   
    if (!isset($t2[$item['iso']])) {
            $t2[$item['iso']] = array();
     }
    
    $newdata =  array (
      'amount' => $item['amount'],
      'start' => $item['start']
    );
    array_push($t2[$item['iso']], $newdata);
}
```

Which outputs the following

```
Array ( [DK] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [amount] => 2 [start] => 2023-03-07 00:00:00 ) [1] => Array ( [amount] => 25 [start] => 2023-03-03 00:00:00 ) ) [AF] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [amount] => 5 [start] => 2023-03-03 00:00:00 ) [1] => Array ( [amount] => 5 [start] => 2023-03-03 00:00:00 ) ) )
```

However it doesn't add the amount to existing start dates. Somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$t2 = [];
foreach ($eventsCountries as $item) {   
    $foundStartDate = false;
    if (!isset($t2[$item['iso']])) {
        $t2[$item['iso']] = array();
    } else {
        foreach ($t2[$item['iso']] as $k => $curr) {
            if ($curr['start'] == $item['start']) {
                $foundStartDate = true;
                $t2[$item['iso']][$k]['amount'] += $item['amount'];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!$foundStartDate) {
        $t2[$item['iso']][] = array(
            'amount' => $item['amount'],
            'start' => $item['start']
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to accomplish. Thank you so much :)